# Shell from meterpreter not responding to commands

Tags: metasploit, meterpreter

Meterpreter session was created, framework latest. Victim machine: Ubuntu

Screenshot of session:

[image]

I am pretty sure the commands used to work before on the same machine. Shell commands are not working after giving shell in meterpreter. All meterpreter command works fine though.

Uploaded payload manually, same issue.

Reseted the victim machine, also did msfupdate.

Comment: Have you done a packet capture to see if it is responding? Have you looked at the victim logs?

Comment: It responds, basically i can run all meterpreter commands perfectly. It's just the shell command inside the meterpreter that produces ambiguity.